# Acronis v11 изменение размера раздела

Tags: hdd, администрирование, раздел

Раньше проблем с ресайзом разделов не было до появления Acronis v11.  Ресайзил диск "Цэ" брал пространство свободное из "Дэ".  НО! почему-что в стэпах отобразилось, что и Е-диск будет изменён в размерах в меньшую сторону на примерно 150 мб (Наверное бывшее свободное пространство на нём).  Почему так происходит? или что я сделал не так.  до 11-ой версии таких проблем не возникало.

**Добавлено:**

[image]

Вот как-бы ресайз Цэ на увеличение, беру свободное от Дэ. Но при применении, см скрин №2!

[image]

Почему-то хочет уменьшиться диск E! Это баг?

Comment: скрин сделай как у тебя получается и мы подскажем что делаешь не так)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Уберите галочку с "Take free space from other volumes", и будет вам счастье!